# what is filtering factor of High Boost Filter?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, filter

I am working on an image processing problem and I need to pass my values through a high boost filter.
For this, we need 2 things; an image and a filtering factor(some value). The filtering factor is not understandable for me.
Can someone guide me here?
I am pasting the code and link to code below:
Link to code: https://github.com/krishna1401/Digital-Image-Processing/blob/master/highBoostFiltering.py

Code block:

```
#Perform High-Boost Filtering over an Image
#High-Boost Filtering Formula
#resultant_pixel_value = A*original_pixel_value - blurred_pixel_value
#where A is the Boosting Factor

import cv2
from google.colab.patches import cv2_imshow
def highBoostFiltering(image,boost_factor):
    #Objective: Performing High-Boost Filtering over an Image
    #Input: Original Image & Filtering Factor
    #Output: Resultant Image
    
    # Blur Kernel Matrix
    #   1/9 1/9 1/9
    #   1/9 1/9 1/9
    #   1/9 1/9 1/9
    
    image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY) #Converting Image to Gray Scale
    resultant_image = image.copy()
    for i in range(1,image.shape[0]-1):
        for j in range(1,image.shape[1]-1):
            blur_factor = (image[i-1, j-1] + image[i-1, j] - image[i-1, j+1] + image[i, j-1] + image[i, j] + image[i, j+1] + image[i+1, j+1] + image[i+1, j] + image[i+1, j+1])/9
            mask = boost_factor*image[i, j] - blur_factor
            resultant_image[i, j] = image[i, j] + mask
            
    return resultant_image

img = cv2.imread('my_plot.png')
factor = input('Enter the value of Filter Factor for High-Boost Filtering : ')
output = highBoostFiltering(img, factor)

cv2_imshow('image',output)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

I have tried several different integers but I think needs some specific value, if anyone has worked on this filter, please guide me.

P.S. Code is python, using the Google Collab.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Your formula looks wrong. It should be `factor * original - blurred` so this line `resultant_image[i, j] = image[i, j] + mask` should just be `resultant_image[i, j] = mask`

Comment: And doing it in nested `for` loops is horrible - doubly so when you have already imported **OpenCV** and are presumably aware that is fast, optimised, tested and efficient.